# Adding methods to existing objects

Tags: javascript

Lets say that I'm creating a simple jQuery or maybe Javascript plugin. For the example here, I would use javascript.

**Selecting an element:**
To select an element I'd say:

```
document.getElementById('test_div');
```

Now, my question is that how can I add custom methods to it? Like maybe something like `.color();`

Such as this :

```
document.getElementById('test_div').color('red');
```

How do I associate this function (or method) with the returned object because normally we would do something like

```
var obj = {property: "I love pandas", color: function(x){...}};
```

I'm really confused here so please explain!

Answer (score 0):

simply this ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/dk1u62gv/2/))

```
Element.prototype.color= function(value) {
    this.style.color = value;
    return this;
};
```

however, it is not a great idea to do it, [read this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/104320/why-is-extending-the-dom-built-in-object-prototypes-a-bad-idea).

why not simply

```
function colorElement( element, colorValue )
{
   element.style.color = colorValue;
}
```

Comment: yeah, but the second method requires us to explicitly pass an object as a parameter. I want the method to somehow figure out what's calling it and add a color to it.. and If I try "this" it gives me an error that it's not a function and of course its not because it's not associated with the returned object..

Comment: like you know, all the cool plugins do it.. just initiate the plugin on an object and it does the rest for you..
$('someElement').coolPlugin();

Comment: Yeah, I know, I tried it... But it's not my question really

Comment: @candh your question is `Now, my question is that how can I add custom methods to it? Like maybe something like .color();` what did i miss?

Comment: @candh you wanted to do `return this` so that you can keep calling methods on an element?

Comment: "to it" that's what you missed. colorElement requires a parameter, "element" Isn't that what we're trying to figure out?

Comment: @candh not yet clear. Can you share/formulate the entire sentence I missed out on?

Comment: @candh Passing the element to be operated on as a parameter, vs. passing it as `this`, are isomorphic (in other words, basically the same). Get over the ridiculous jQuery-like chaining fixation. It's time to move on now.

Comment: @torazaburo What is the pragmatical alternative to the "ridiculous jQuery-like chaining fixation"?